# Show that $\frac{P^{\prime \prime}(x)-P^{\prime \prime}(\alpha)}{x-\alpha}=\frac{P^{\prime \prime}(\beta)-P^{\prime \prime}(\alpha)}{\beta-\alpha}.$

Tags: calculus, polynomials

Let $P$ be a polynomial of degree less than or equal to $3$ defined on $]\alpha , \beta [$ by its values $P(\alpha), P(\beta), P^{\prime \prime}(\alpha), P^{\prime \prime}(\beta)$.
Show that $$\frac{P^{\prime \prime}(x)-P^{\prime \prime}(\alpha)}{x-\alpha}=\frac{P^{\prime \prime}(\beta)-P^{\prime \prime}(\alpha)}{\beta-\alpha}.$$
i know just that if $P$ is a polynomial of degree less than or equal to $3$ so   $P^{\prime \prime}(x)$ is linear.

Comment: You already did most of the job. You can interpret that ratio as the slope of the line passing though two points of the curve $(x,P''(x))$ but since you know that the curve is a straight line, the slope is constant

Comment: @Thomas thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If P(x) is a polynomial of degree less than or equal to one then  $P^{\prime \prime}(x)$ will be $0$.

If P(x) is a polynomial of degree two then  $P^{\prime \prime}(x)$ will be constant.

If P(x) is of degree 3 ,then  consider $P^{\prime \prime}(x)$ as $mx+n$ and you will get $\frac{P^{\prime \prime}(x)-P^{\prime \prime}(\alpha)}{x-\alpha}=\frac{P^{\prime \prime}(\beta)-P^{\prime \prime}(\alpha)}{\beta-\alpha}=m$

Comment: Thank you for the answer . But how can i get the expression of m ?

Comment: @Geravit3 I have just assumed  P′′(x) to be mx+n